# Between Date Range Filter PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

What is the easiest way to create a filter on a table that is between date ranges?

I have a table.field called tag_enquiries.datecreated. How do I get a filter for between the first of June to the last day of June. I am sure this will be in a measure.

Comment: Have you tried `DATESBETWEEN()`, `PARALLELPERIOD()`, `PREVIOUSMONTH()` or any other [Time Intelligence Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your table, under Visualizations select the Fields symbol then under Filters, open your date field.  You can choose "Advanced filtering" and create a logical construct such as:

[image]

Of course, you can also deploy without a filter and use a slicer on a date field and select "Between" from the list

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Visualizations tab Select filter option and assign date data in value. After that select data and visualize

[image]